# Convert Excel sheet to PDF without margins and whitespace

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file and after convert to PDF, there are many empty margins in page. But if I convert the Excel file to JPG and with Acrobat Reader convert this JPG to PDF, then there is no margin and empty margins.

I adjust page zoom, printarea, scale to fit, software printer, print to file, save as PDF and etc and not working.

Is there any macro to do it for the entire workbook, without any empty margins? If this macro could have these options would be very good:

1. Do it for the entire workbook automatically and with question.
2. For each sheet make a seperate PDF and every export PDF file name is same as sheet name in my Excel file path.
3. Print area by default selected for each sheets, for to convert in PDF.
4. Export PDF use minimum size PDF format.

As an example I attached the `xlsm` file to try on it in Google Drive:
[main.xlsm](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qKHvYEFyyTnzyNL87pLx9zu0ShIM_4nG/view?usp=sharing)

I use this VBA to convert the Excel sheets to PDF for the entire workbook. This code has empty margins for each page from side and top and bottom. How can make PDF files without margin in VBA Excel?

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Print_PDF()
    Dim Awb As Workbook
    Dim Snr As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set Awb = ActiveWorkbook
     
    For Each ws In Awb.Sheets
        If Not ws.Name = "Sheet1" Then
            'Sheets(ws.Name).Copy
            Awb.Sheets(ws.Name).Copy
            'Sheets(ws.Name).Select
            ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
              Awb.Path & "\" & Awb.Sheets(ws.Name).Name & ".pdf", _
              Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
              IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
           
            ActiveWindow.Close False
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you 'convert' Excel (sheet, workbook) to pdf? Manually, or using VBA? If using VBA (I can see VBA tag), please edit your question and post the code you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you set your print area to the range you want to print:

   ```
   ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:C14"
   ```
2. Make sure you set your page margins to zero:

   ```
   With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
       .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
       .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
       .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
       .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
   End With
   ```
3. Make sure you select the native Windows PDF printer *"Microsoft Print to PDF"*.

   ```
   Application.ActivePrinter = "Microsoft Print to PDF on Ne02:"
   ```

   Note that the number in the end `Ne02:` changes on every computer. See here ([Setting Default Printer to Microsoft Print to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63037229/setting-default-printer-to-microsoft-print-to-pdf)) for a code to find out the correct printer name including the `Ne##:`

In this example you can see that the black frame starts in the left top corner witout magin.

[image]
*<sup>Image 1: PDF without margins (sorry for the German screenshot).</sup>*